# How to derive two angles in an ambiguous case

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

***the* question**

find all possible values of angle PQR if PQ=12 and QR=$4\sqrt{3}$ and the area of triangle PQR is 12$\sqrt{6}$.

**my steps**

there are two versions of methodology

*version A:drawing*

I constructed a triangle PQR and drew an altitude from point R to base PQ and called the point of intersection at point W. Then we have right triangle PWR. Then angle RWQ is a right angle. Then we set $\frac{1}{2}(12)(x)=12\sqrt{6}$ where X is the length of the altitude. from there i used trig to find angle WRQ then clearly RQW can be deduced to be 45 degrees

*version B: using quick trig*

Solving for $\frac{1}{2}PQ*QRsin\angle{PQR}$
solves the same answer

**MY question**

Some how there is another answer which is 135. I was wondering how can this be so?. I can only get 45 degrees as an answer.

Comment: Hint: sin(45)=sin(135)

Comment: When you construct the triangle, if you are using intersections and such, do you consider all possible intersections?

Comment: @shardulc i believe there is only one intersection to make an altitude starting from one angle. or am i wrong?

Comment: $PQ = 12$, so you draw that segment. $QR = 4\sqrt{3}$, so you draw a circle of that radius... then when you construct the appropriate height of the triangle, won't it intersect the circle in two points?

Comment: Sorry, i think you mis understood when i explained about the altitude. i meant that from point R you draw an altitude that intersects at a 90 degree angle to line PQ, clearly theres only 1 such line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of user 3141, I have realized that when constructing a Unit Circle, on the quadrant two and one, there are values where the sines are equal. therefore sin 45= sin 135 because 180-45=135. therefore there are two answers